# Which operator gets invoked upon object evaluation?

Tags: c++

I would like to print the id of my object when the object is being evaluated (third line in my main function "one = two; should output "Object id: 2"). I know that the assignment operator is only invoked for the lvalue, a conversation operator to itself will never be called and I don't want to use the function call operator.

Any ideas how this can be done, which operator must I overload?

P.S.: Please ignore any saneness of the code, I only care about identifying the right to-be-overloaded operator.

```
#include <iostream>    
class Object
{
public:
  Object( int id ) : id_( id )
  {
  }     
  //Assignment operator only invoked for lvalue
  Object& operator= (const Object& other)
  {
    std::cout << "Object id: " << id_ << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }    
  //Conversion operator to itself will never be called
  operator Object() const
  {
    return *(this);
  }    
  //Function call operator - not what I mean
  Object operator()()
  {
    std::cout << "Object id: " << id_ << std::endl;
    return *(this);
  }    
private:
  int id_;
};

int main()
{
  Object one(1);
  Object two(2);
  one = two;
  one = two();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want the assignment operator to print other's id, just do that. It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve though.

Comment: @Mat I think the problem is that there's no getter for the other's ``id_`` and that it's a private member variable.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: that's not a problem.

Comment: @Mat how is the operator overloader function supposed to access the other's ``id_`` then? It doesn't have access to the parameter's private member variables.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Yes it does, it's the same class.

Comment: @Mat Oh, I thought that only worked for friend functions, my mistake.

Comment: @Christian: Are you looking for the statement `one;` to print `Object id: 1\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of "object evaluation" isn't really present in C++. An *expression* can be evaluated, of course, and operator overloading fits into this: `foo = bar` invokes any overloaded `operator=` which matches the operands (and in the case of `operator=` specifically, must be a member of the LHS class type). But it's the assignment that's being evaluated, not `foo` or `bar` (and note that in the context of the operator overload, these are present as pointers or references, so it's not inevitable that either one will be evaluated at all).

The appropriate solution here will depend on what it is you're trying to accomplish. But there's no one function that automatically fires whenever your code mentions `bar`.

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers. I picked Sneftel's answers as it made me realize that there is no such thing as an "operator that generically gets invoked upon evaluation". And yes, Bill, Patrick and others, you're right that in my example we could have done the print with the assignment operator. But then again, if the object would have been evaluated in a different context, the assignment op is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>    
class Object
{
public:
  Object( int id ) : id_( id )
  {
  }     
  //Assignment operator only invoked for lvalue
  Object& operator= (const Object& other)
  {
    std::cout << "Object id: " << other.id_ << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }    
private:
  int id_;
};

int main()
{
  Object one(1);
  Object two(2);
  one = two;
  return 0;
}
```

I tried this to see if Mat was right, turns out it compiles and prints `"Object id: 2"` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

So, this line:

```
one = two;
```

Will call this function that you already have:

```
Object& operator= (const Object& other)
{
    std::cout << "Object id: " << id_ << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

However, let's note that there are two `Object` objects that are visible in that function.

```
Object& operator= (const Object& other)
{
    std::cout << "Object(" << this->id_ << ")";
    std::cout << " = ";
    std::cout << "Object(" << other.id_ << ")";
    std::cout << "\n";
    return *this;
}
```

You can see a full example where we run this code at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/6hbDkp).